# Google Signin: Detect User Granting Authentication

Tags: authentication, google-signin, google-api-js-client

I've used 2 versions of the basic google sigin code provided by google:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

This code tells me when the user is signed in with google.

What I need now is code that will be invoked only when the user has clicked "Allow" on the google popup that Google would like to View the user's profile, so I can detect when the user has clicked on that button.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it:

```
function onSuccess(googleUser) {
  if (googleUser.getAuthResponse().hasOwnProperty("access_token"))
      { /* CODE TO BE EXECUTED ONLY AFTER USER HAS ALLOWED ACCESS */ }
}
```